# 27MB IPA with just GStreamer iOS Framework... how do I make much smaller?

Tags: ios, gstreamer, multimedia

I'm very interested in using GStreamer's iOS framework http://docs.gstreamer.com/display/GstSDK/Installing+for+iOS+development for video streaming, but when I add the framework to a blank project and add a few lines of code to take advantage of its powerful features, the final IPA is 27MB. This is just way to big to be adding to my project, what is the best way to go about stripping this down the the bare necessities as I'm sure I'm only using a small percent of the code that is included in the SDK.

Here's a pic showing the package contents of the IPA:
[image: Package Contents]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the gst_ios_main.h you can disable all the plugins that you don't need (make sure to enable linker optimizations so that unused code is removed). If that's not enough, you can build your own stripped down version of the iOS binaries with http://cgit.freedesktop.org/gstreamer/cerbero/ (you need to remove things from the .package and .recipe files to only build what you need). Just disabling things from gst_ios_main.h should be enough in 99% of the cases though.

Note that by default you'll build applications for multiple architectures, as such the resulting application will be rather large. Depending on your use case you can drop some architectures.

On another note, gstreamer.com is providing an completely outdated version of GStreamer and is in no way related to the GStreamer project. The official website is http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org .

Comment: App Thinning in Xcode 7 does this by default when you upload you binary to the AppStore.

Comment: It only does that for code that is actually unused. Plugins that are enabled, are "used" in the code (references to their symbols) but they might or might not be used for anything useful at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

SDKs have their source code encapsulated away from you, the user. You get access only to header files. Thus you just can't extract some class from it because you don't have access to the implementation file.
Of course if this library is opensource you can attempt to isolate one class, but sometimes everything is so deeply connected, that it is close to impossible.